# Is there any way to autoindent a section of text in vimscript?

Tags: vim

I'd like to autoindent a range of lines in a Vim plugin I'm writing, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way. Short of an actual vimscript command, I've been looking for ex-mode commands I could use to trigger autoindenting, but I haven't found a way there either.

Is there any way to trigger the autoindentation of a range of lines in Vim, besides hitting just hitting "="?

Comment: why can't you use `=`? you could do `normal! 3G=10G`

Comment: `normal` is what I was missing, didn't realize I could use it to execute normal mode commands in ex mode. If you write an answer instead of a comment I'll give it to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why can't you use =? 
you could do

```
:normal! 3G=10G
```

to auto-indent 3,10 lines